# Master PyQt5 GUI with pushbuttons that open additional GUI

Tags: python, widget, pyqt5

Using Python3 and PyQt5, I want to have a GUI that has a button on it that, when pressed, opens another widget which also has buttons and other controls. In the future, the master GUI will have many buttons that will open many additional widgets. I'm looking at having one widget with an embedded matplotlib.pyplot. At the moment, I am struggling to open a second widget.

Main Program

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from gui import Ui_MainWindow as Ui_MainWindow1
from gui2 import Ui_MainWindow as Ui_MainWindow2

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui_gui = Ui_MainWindow1()
        self.ui_gui.setupUi(self)


        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.on_pb_clicked)
        self.graph = Graph(self)

    def on_pb_clicked(self):

        print('pb clicked')
        self.graph.show()


class Graph(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Graph, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui_graph = Ui_MainWindow2()
        self.ui_graph.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow1()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

gui = gui2. Both look like the below.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(282, 219)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.pb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pb.setObjectName("pb")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 282, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pb.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pb"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to click the button on gui and have the gui2 appear. NB gui will not equal gui2 in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Window` and `Graph` inherit from `Ui_Window1` and `Ui_Window2`, respectively, you should call `self.setupUi(self)` in `Window.__init__` and `Graph.__init__` instead of creating separate instances of `Ui_Window1` and `Ui_Window2`, i.e.

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.on_pb_clicked)
        self.graph = Graph(self)

        # just to see the two windows side-by-side
        self.move(500, 400)
        self.graph.move(self.x()+self.width()+20, self.y())

    def on_pb_clicked(self):
        print('pb clicked')
        self.graph.show()


class Graph(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Graph, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

The main part of the program should then be something like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Window()
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I was at that for a while. Do I need all this:     ```def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)```. Or can this be trimmed down as well?

Answer (score 0):

You use `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()` to enable the automatic calling of the `on_pb_clicked()` slot.

You do not need to use `self.pb.clicked.connect(self.on_pb_clicked)`
You need `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from gui_1 import Ui_MainWindow as Ui_MainWindow1
from gui_2 import Ui_MainWindow as Ui_MainWindow2

class Graph(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Graph, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("window Graph")
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 260, 282, 219))
#        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.on_pb_clicked)         # ---

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()                                       # +++
    def on_pb_clicked(self):       
        print('pb clicked -> Graph')


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("main Window")
#        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.on_pb_clicked)         # ---
        self.graph = Graph(self) 

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()                                       # +++
    def on_pb_clicked(self): 
        print('pb clicked -> "main Window')
        self.graph.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]